# With in statements how do they work in SAS for two different variables?

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I want to use the with in statement in SAS but I am not sure how it works with two variables in a where statement with dates. 
Can anyone give suggestions to the last line of code?

```
proc sql; 
    create table work.users as 
    select t1.age 
           t1.ID
           t1.DateTime1 
           t2.DateTime2
    from work.database.table t1
    left join work.users2 on datepart(t1.Datetime1) is within 2 days datepart(t2.DateTime2)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure SAS supports `within`.  You can use the `between` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like david25272 said in his comment, `within` will not work in SAS. You will have to use `between`:

```
proc sql; 
    create table work.users as 
    select t1.age 
           t1.ID
           t1.DateTime1 
           t2.DateTime2
    from work.database.table t1
    left join work.users2 
      on datepart(t1.Datetime1) between datepart(t2.DateTime2)-2 and datepart(t2.DateTime2)+2
quit;
```